# Working with more than 1 fragment per Page on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've always worked with `FragmentActivity` and `TabHost` to add/remove/replace `Fragment` programmatically.

What I was using was:

```
public void addFragments(String tabName, Fragment fragment,
        boolean animate, boolean add, Bundle bundle) {
    currentSelectedTab = tabName;

    if (add) {
        hMapTabs.get(tabName).add(fragment);
    }
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    if (animate) {
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    }
    if (bundle!=null){
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment, tabName);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

}

public void removeFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).get(
            hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).size() - 2);
    hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).remove(
            hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).size() - 1);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

With that, everything works OK.

Now I'm trying to manage this Fragment's **behavior** on a page of my `ViewPager`.

I've been searching on StackOverFlow for three hours and I get confused everytime more and more. Tried with public functions on `FragmentPagerAdapter` for example.

And what only worked makes me a white blank screen on adding Fragments.

How would you do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) helpful when I first started out using `ViewPager`

Comment: but how did you do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my problem but I don't know if it's effective.

I'm defining a `HashMap` to keep my Fragments:

```
private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Fragment>> hMapTabs = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Fragment>>();
```

then I initializate it and I add my first fragments of every position (in this case, the fragments are the same).

```
    hMapTabs.put(0, new ArrayList<Fragment>());
    hMapTabs.put(1, new ArrayList<Fragment>());
    hMapTabs.put(2, new ArrayList<Fragment>());

    hMapTabs.get(0).add(new PrimerFragment());
    hMapTabs.get(1).add(new PrimerFragment());
    hMapTabs.get(2).add(new PrimerFragment());
```

and I set my adapter to my ViewPager. This would be the `FragmentAdapterPager`:

```
public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    final int NUM_ITEMS = 3; // number of tabs
    FragmentManager fm;
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Fragment>> hMapTabs;
    public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Fragment>> hMapTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
        this.hMapTabs = hMapTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return hMapTabs.get(position).get(hMapTabs.get(position).size()-1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String tabLabel = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            tabLabel = "tab1";
            break;
        case 1:
            tabLabel = "tab2";
            break;
        case 2:
            tabLabel = "tab3";
            break;
     }

        return tabLabel;

    }
}
```

from every fragment, I can add or remove fragments with the functions:

```
public void addFragment(int position, Fragment frag) {
    hMapTabs.get(position).add(frag);
    mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), hMapTabs);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
}

public void removeFragment(int position) {
    hMapTabs.get(position).remove(
            hMapTabs.get(position).size() - 1);
    mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), hMapTabs);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    if (hMapTabs.get(position).size() <= 1) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        removeFragment(position);
    }

}
```

but what I can't do is adding an Animation... how would I do it? :D